# "Happens" or "Happened"

Tags: meaning

Two sentences which are given below. which sentence should be correct while conversion?

One problem happens, whenever i go to market.

One problem is happened, whenever i go to market.

Comment: a problem occurs, not happens. 
so, "a problem occurs everytime I go to the market" should be your choice.

Answer (score 2):

*BE* + past participle, as in *is happened*, is the **passive** construction, in which the entity which receives the action (the direct object) is 'recast' as the subject.

But *happen* is an intransitive verb (it never takes a direct object), so it cannot be cast in the passive voice.

Consequently, only the first of your two examples is grammatically acceptable.

> One problem happens, whenever i go to market.

However, as vickyace tells you, we do not ordinarily use *happen* with *problem*; *arise* or *come up* or *occur* would be better here. Moreover, using *one* as the determiner here implies (in the absence of more context) that you intend your addressee to understand that exactly one problem—not two or more problems, or no problem—arises every time you go to market. I suspect that what you really mean is this:

> A problem arises whenever I go to market.

In some contexts, however, *one* might be appropriate—for instance, if you are singling out one specific problem of several which have already been mentioned:

> I mostly know where to buy stuff now, I no longer have to translate the local currency into dollars, and I've even mastered (I think) the kilo/liter/meter system. But one problem still comes up whenever I go to market—everybody expects to negotiate prices, and I'm just no good at haggling.

Comment: problem + arise is even commoner, at least according to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=problem+happens%2C+problem+occurs%2C+problem+arises&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproblem%20happens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproblem%20occurs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproblem%20arises%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @msam Quite true - I will edit to reflect this. Thank you.